# How do I stop enemies from spawning in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to stop enemies from spawning when one of them hit the "finish" tag.

Here's the script which spawn enemies:

```
public class spawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject enemy;
    private float spawnpoint;
    public float xlimit = 12f;
    float spawnNewEnemyTimer = 1f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        spawnNewEnemyTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (spawnNewEnemyTimer <= 0 )
        {
            spawnNewEnemyTimer = 3;
            GameObject nemico = Instantiate(enemy);
        }
    }
```

Here's the script which make the enemies appear at random point and move:

```
public class nemici : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed = 4f;

    public GameObject enemy;
    public float xlimit = 12f;
    private float currentPosition;
    public GameObject spawn;
    bool endGame = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (endGame == false)
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
            newPosition.x = Random.Range(-xlimit, xlimit);
            transform.position = newPosition;
        }
        else if (endGame == true)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (endGame == false)
        {
            //per farlo muovere verso il basso
            Vector3 movimento = new Vector3(0f, -speed, 0f);    //(x, y, z)
            transform.position += movimento * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (endGame == true)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(enemy);
        }

        else if (other.tag == "Finish")
        {
            Debug.Log("hai perso!");
            endGame = true;
        }
      }
   }
```

What's wrong with this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic that spawns new enemies is in the spawn class. The logic that decides whether you should stop spawning enemies, resides on the enemy class.

You are succesfully setting the endgame boolean to true whenever you want enemies to stop spawning when they hit an object with the finish tag.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.tag == "Finish"){
        Debug.Log("hai perso!");
        endGame = true;
    }
}
```

Great! But you are not actually using it to stop spawns.
So far this variable is local to each enemy. So if you include checks in the start and update functions, they will only activate for the specific enemy that touched touched the finish object. This is not what you want.

You want the Spawn class to check the endgame variable, and if it is active, to stop spawning enemies.

To do this you will have to somehow be able to access the endgame variable from Spawn, What I recommend is that you make the endGame variable a member of te Spawn class. And that you include a reference to the Spawn in each enemy.

All together it might look something like this:

```
public class Spawn: MonoBehaviour{
    public boolean endgame = false;
    GameObject nemico = Instantiate(Enemy);
    nemico.ParentSpawn = this
}

public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour{
    public Spawn spawn;
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (other.tag == "Finish"){
            Spawn.endGame = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use the endgame boolean from within Spawn to check if you should keep spawning enemies.